# Client Zoom in OpenLayers with Google layer

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I'm displaying some features on a map, but the features are somewhat on the small side and can't be easily viewed at default zoom levels. Using the [Client Zoom](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html) example, I was able to enable acceptable zoom levels on an OSM layer. However, I'd like the features to be displayed on a satellite/hybrid layer.

Google is my first choice, but I have been unable to get client zoom working properly on their hybrid layer. Attempting to zoom in past the server's maximum zoom level results in the feature itself being zoomed, but not the map tile around it.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Other satellite layers would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client zoom works for grid layers (OpenLayers.Layer.Grid) only. Google layers aren't grid layers. Bing layers are.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps has fixed zoom level for its tiles that it is not supported fractionalZoom in Google maps.

For people who dont know what is continues zooming that it works for requesting tiles at higher resolutions and stretching the layer div as appropriate.

Though Google layer, you can use layer.bing which i heard that it supports it...

i hope it helps you...